# symbol at particular location in line chart with core plot

Tags: iphone, ios, graph, core-plot, linechart

I want to draw line chart using core plot

i have x-axis with time (1,2,3,...13,14...00)
and y-axis with numbers(0-50-100-150-200-....500)

now at each coordinate(x,y) i want to put symbol like circle with color

for example 
at x-axis - time 4'o clock and 
y-axis - number 65

at x-axis - time 13'o clock and 
y-axis - number 25

at x-axis - time 14'o clock and 
y-axis - number 15

at x-axis - time 23'o clock and 
y-axis - number 5

so at each (x,y) want to put symbol and then draw line using these symbol

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Read about [CPPlotSymbol](http://florent.clairambault.fr/downloads/iPhone/core-plot-doc/interface_c_p_plot_symbol.html)..You can adjust CPPlotSymbol size as you like.

A small example..

```
CPScatterPlot *dataPlot; (dataPlot obtained elsewhere)

// Add points to this plot
CPPlotSymbol *circlePlotSymbol = [CPPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
circlePlotSymbol.fill = [CPFill fillWithColor:dataPlot.dataLineStyle.lineColor];
circlePlotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6, 6);

dataPlot.plotSymbol = circlePlotSymbol;
```

Comment: thanks for advice but i am asking for a symbol on particular location